# Is it possible to call a function ONLY on the first run?

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I am developing an app using Telerik's Nativescript. I would like to know whether it's possible to call a function the first time the app is ran, but not for each consecutive run.

My first thoughts were to ship a one line text file with the content `false`. On the first run I would check this file and get the value. If it were `false` I'd run the function and then update the text file content to `true`, otherwise I'd let the app continue as normal.

I think there must be a better, more efficient way to do this. Any ideas folks?

Comment: How about `cookies/localStorage` ? There is no full-proof client side solution for this..

Comment: Imagine a raging river after a rainstorm.  You're doing the equivalent of going, "Hmm, I got the downstream thing, but how I swim *upstream*?"  That isn't to say it is impossible, but you have to put into question your reasons for doing so.  I would argue that there's a conceptual error here that led you to decide that running a script once was the best solution, and I have no doubt that it is the best solution for a bad decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've no idea why you're getting a all these browser technology answers but as you're using **NativeScript** you most probably want to take a look at the [Application Settings](https://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/application-settings/HOW-TO) module.

A value set with Application Settings will persist for as long as the app is installed on the device. If the user is re-installing the app it'll (of course) be reset.

It's as easy as:

```
var appSettings = require("application-settings");
if(!appSettings.getBoolean("hasRunned", false)) {
    // Do the stuff you want to do on first run
    // and then set it to true
    appSettings.setBoolean("hasRunned", true);
}
```